# Automapper - From View to Domain

Tags: automapper

I have read that a best practice approach for going from View to Domain is not to reverse map objects, but to use a Command Processing Architecture. However, with the exception of this post - http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/08/25/restify-extending-asp-net-mvc.aspx, I have not been able to dig up anything about that.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction with regards to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not such thing as Best Practice! Try to do reverse mapping - if it works, go for it! If you run into a lot of friction, it's because your domain is complex - and doesn't fit well with this scenario.

A simple way of providing this in your domain is simply:

```
Customer.UpdatePersonalInformation(personalInformationDto);
```

And do the work inside there.

Comment: Jimmy. Thanks for your answer. I love Automapper.